# How can AC be listed as a single voltage

Tags: information-theory

How can AC be listed as a **single voltage** (e.g 240V AC) when it constantly varies and what does this have **to do with RMS Voltage.**

Comment: How can this be listed as a mathematics question?

Comment: You could read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_current#Mathematics_of_AC_voltages) and see if that helps.

Comment: The RMS voltage _is_ the "single voltage" by which an AC power source is described. That's what it has to do with RMS voltage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AC voltage is listed as the RMS voltage even though it varies.  So in the U.S. for example, standard outlets are 110-120V (meaning RMS voltage).  They calculate the RMS voltage in the following way:

Suppose that the voltage as a function of time is $V(t)=A\sin(Bt+\phi)$ where $A, B$, and $\phi$ are constants which determine amplitude, frequency (60 hz in U.S.), and phase shift.  Then the "displayed" voltage is

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b} A^{2}\sin^{2}(Bt+\phi)dt}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are chosen so that the length of the interval $[a, b]$ is an integer (not zero) multiple of the period of $\sin(Bt)$, i.e. $b-a=\frac{2\pi k}{B}$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$.

Check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square for more info.  You actually don't need the calculus to compute RMS Voltage for these types of waveforms.